# PHP Heredoc won't display variables in HTML - WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, heredoc

I have written some functions in my functions.php in my theme. I have:

```
$usrProfileHTML = <<<EOD
<div class="eUserProfile">
    <div class="eUsrImage">
        <img src="{$envUserProfile['eUsrImage']}" alt="{$envUserProfile['eUserName']}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="eProfileData">
        <div class="eUsrUsername">
            {$envUserProfile['eUsrUsername']}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
EOD;


$fUserData = false;
$fUserPurchases = false;
$envatoChecked = false;
$envUserProfile = false;

add_shortcode( 'envato_mn', 'support_envato_shortcode_953225hfdjs' );
function support_envato_shortcode_953225hfdjs() {
    global $envUserProfile;
    global $fullEnvatoUser;
    global $envatoButton;
    global $usrProfileHTML;

    if($fullEnvatoUser == true) {
        #die(print_r($envUserProfile));
        return $usrProfileHTML;
    } else {
        return $envatoButton;
    }
}
```

and my variables aren't shown at all, nor do they echo values. What could be the issue?

Comment: Using variables in a heredoc block works perfectly fine in my code. Are you sure the variables (or rather elements) you wanna use, are defined and not empty?

Comment: that's a wordpress plugin. That's inside shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I had typos when I's populating $envUserProfile variable. Fixed.